# Error Bars for Incidence of a Rare Medical Complication

Tags: statistical-significance, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I am making a plot of the incidence of a medical complication by the drug dose used.  The incidence is very small, and so I am getting huge error bars using standard deviation-based methods, even though the dataset is well-powered.

How would you calculate error bars on a chart looking at frequency of an event such as this?

Comment: What makes you think you should expect smaller errorbars. Try to bootstrap it. Rare events come with high uncertainty.